# Minimization using logarithmic barrier function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm thinking of the quadratic problem(QP)
\begin{align}
&\underset{x\in \mathrm{R}^n}{\mathrm{Minimize}}\ \ \  \frac{1}{2}x^\top{}Qx + f^\top{}x\\
&\mathrm{subject\ to}\ \ \ \ a_ix \leq b_i\ (i = 1, \cdots, m)
\end{align}
, where $Q$ is positive definite, using logarithmic penalty method.
Let the interior of the feasible region be $D$, and reformulating, we can get
\begin{equation}
\underset{x\in D}{\mathrm{Minimize}}\ \ \  \frac{1}{2}x^\top{}Qx + f^\top{}x
-\mu_k\sum_{i=1}^m\log{(b_i - a_ix)}
\end{equation}
in the $k$-th iteration.
My question is, 
1. Does this penalized problem has a minimum in the feasible area $D$ ?
2. Is the minimum unique?

Comment: *If* the feasible region has a non-empty interior, then 1) yes, and 2) yes. The positive definiteness of $Q$ enables that guarantee. If $Q$ were only positive semidefinite, we could not say so without further qualification, since the problem could be unbounded below. One such qualification would be that $D$ has a non-empty interior and is bounded.

Comment: @Michael Grant Thank you for your answering! I'll appreciate it if you could give me some proof, or show me some material which has the proof.

Comment: If I had that for you, I would've posted an answer, not a comment :-)

Comment: @Michael Grant That's right. Anyway, thank you for your kindness. I'll try to prove the fact myself (though I have no idea now).

Comment: The linchpin is the strong convexity of the objective!

Comment: I do like my karma but if someone else offers a proof they will have my vote as well as yours!